# Disabling/enabling language specific mappings in Vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I have `:set keymap=russian-jcukenwin`.

In this keyboard mapping `` ` `` maps to `ё`. I want to unmap this backtick.

```
:lmap `
l  `           *@ё
:lunmap `
E31: No such mapping
```

Why `` lunmap ` `` gives an error? How can I unmap it?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't understand why `lunmap` throws an error, I have found a workaround.

Find a path to `russian-jcukenwin.vim` by using `:verbose lmap`. Copy this file into `~/.vim/keymap/` directory. Then comment or remove undesired mappings. That's it.